How to Populate Resource.resx file Value from database?
In code below I'm using if else statement to localize text. What is correct way to populate data from your DB using localization?
@model List<Banner>
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home";
    var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
}

    <section class="banner mycontainer">

        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
            @foreach (var banner in Model)
            {
                <div class="@(banner.Id==Model.FirstOrDefault(banner).Id?"carousel-item active":"carousel-item")">
                    <div class="banner__title">
                        <h1>
                           @if(currentCulture=="en")
                            {
                                @banner.TitleEN
                            }
                            else if (currentCulture == "ru")
                            {
                                @banner.TitleRU
                            }
                            else @banner.TitleAZ
                        </h1>

I tried to use IStringLocalizerFactory, but I couldn't.
